# PHP Equivalant for INET_NTOA and INET_ATON

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

Are there any PHP equivalents for these two functions? I tried searching but couldn't see anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/ip2long) and [`long2ip()`](http://php.net/long2ip).

```
$ip = '192.0.34.166';
printf("%u\n", ip2long($ip)); // 3221234342
```

As it notes in the manual:

> Note: Because PHP's integer type is
>   signed, and many IP addresses will
>   result in negative integers, you need
>   to use the "%u" formatter of sprintf()
>   or printf() to get the string
>   representation of the unsigned IP
>   address.

Answer (score 2):

Here PHP alternative functions (simple copy/paste in your program) -

```
function inet_aton($ip)
{
    $ip = trim($ip);
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)) return 0;
    return sprintf("%u", ip2long($ip));  
}


function inet_ntoa($num)
{
    $num = trim($num);
    if ($num == "0") return "0.0.0.0";
    return long2ip(-(4294967295 - ($num - 1))); 
}
```